# Mock ReactiveSecurityContextHolder

Tags: java, mockito

how can I mock ReactiveSecurityContextHolder in the tests so it will be possible to get into the lambda `flatmap`

```
ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .flatMap(authentication -> {})
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You just need to add `@WithMockUser("customUserName")` on test.

Comment: This does not work. `@WithMockUser` modifies the standard SecurityContextHolder. To see why check out [spring.io](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser)

Answer (score 12):

To mock `Authentication` held in the `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder` you need to use [`TestSecurityContextHolder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/test/context/TestSecurityContextHolder.html) and [`ReactorContextTestExecutionListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/test/context/support/ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.html):

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ReactiveSecurityContextHolderTests {

  @Mock
  private Authentication authentication;

  private TestExecutionListener reactorContextTestExecutionListener =
      new ReactorContextTestExecutionListener();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn("token");

    TestSecurityContextHolder.setAuthentication(authentication);
    reactorContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(null);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    reactorContextTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(null);
  }

  //...tests...
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `SpringRunner` with `@TestExecutionListeners` annotation instead of `MockitoJUnitRunner`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(ReactorContextTestExecutionListener.class)
public class ReactiveSecurityContextHolderTests {

  private static Authentication authentication;

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUp() throws Exception {
    authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    when(authentication.getPrincipal()).thenReturn("token");

    TestSecurityContextHolder.setAuthentication(authentication);
  }

  //...tests...
}
```

Find more information in the https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html

Comment: Second method seems nicer, but JUnit 5 does not have the @RunWith annotation. For me, @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) did NOT work.

Comment: Just a note that `reactorContextTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(null);` must be called **every time** you set the authentication context using `TestSecurityContextHolder.setAuthentication(authentication);`.  This is important to rememember if you are overriding the authentication context for a single test, for example.